# Is there a comprehensive list of function upgrades for Transistor?

Tags: transistor

Can someone provide a list or writeup/summary of how each function affects other functions as an upgrade?  The Function interface is just horribly frustrating to me.  I keep flipping back and forth between pages trying to figure out how each affects what.  I just got past the first boss and I only just realized that pairing Function A with Function B isn't the same as pairing Function B with Function A for example.  Is there a better way to see how Upgrades work right away as I'm slotting them, or do I have to go to the Upgrade screen every time?

Comment: I saw this in the close votes queue. It's probably because you've asked to be directed to a list, rather than simply asking for the list. That would result in a link answer, which would be considered a poor answer. Just ask for the list, and a good answer will contain the whole list.

Comment: might I ask why the self answer was deleted? It looks pretty comprehensive.

Comment: I got it from IGN and it turns out their information was mistaken: whoever wrote it up just ended up putting the same upgrades under every function.    Unfortunately I didn't realize until I posted it.

Comment: You realize that the reason nobody has answered this is that you're looking for a list of 256 combinations, right?